# apache load mod_wsgi failed

Tags: python, apache

the reason is

> httpd: Syntax error on line 120 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so, 10): Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Python\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so\n 
>   Reason: image not found

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please, take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0):

Some details can be found in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX

What version of MacOS X are you using and what Python installation?

Better be quick before the thought police here hound you out of town.

Comment: the version of macos x is 10.9.4
python is Python 2.7.6 --  64-bit
I don't understand the "Reason image not found"

Comment: What do you get when you run 'file /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so'? As document covers, what is happening is the mod_wsgi.so does not have compiled into it the code for the specific architecture that Apache is trying to run as. So if Apache is trying to run as i386 and mod_wsgi.so has no i386 code in it and only x86_64, then it will not run and you will get that error. So start out by indicating what architectures are compiled into it. Rather than do it here, go post your problem in the mod_wsgi mailing list. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Asking_Your_Questions